# Is this phrase a CP or another DP?

Tags: syntax, x-bar-theory

If I were to have a DP, such as "the car which I had washed in the garage", the "which I had washed in the garage" sounds a lot like a CP. However, I have never seen CP's embedded within a DP, only within VP's. Would this even be possible?
Or is the "which" a pronoun that forms another DP with the 'I' that is embedded within the first DP 'the car'?
I am still learning complex x-bar trees, so bear with me.

Comment: It would be easier to parse with a full sentence or utterance.

Comment: Yes, that's a CP. See just one example [here](http://www.sfu.ca/person/dearmond/322/322.relative.clauses.htm) (not all images work for me, but the one that does has a relative clause.

Comment: X-Bar stuff! I much prefer the trad analysis where the sequence "the car which I had washed in the garage" is classified as an NP

Comment: Further, if "the car which I had washed in the garage" really was a DP, then "the" would be head, which is of course ridiculous. It's better to say that the nominal "car" is head, with the determinative "the" as determiner, and the head modified by the relative clause "which I had washed in the garage".